# Nesting an OBJECT_CONSTRUCT result inside an JSON array when unloading data from Snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT` on a table with multiple rows as follows:

```
COPY INTO @%mytable
  FROM (
    SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
      'id', id, 'first_name', first_name,
      'last_name', last_name, 'city', city, 'state', state
    ) FROM mytable
  )
  FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = JSON);
```

This produces the following kind of JSON output:

```
{"city":"Salt Lake City","first_name":"Ryan","id":1,"last_name":"Dalton","state":"UT"}
{"city":"Birmingham","first_name":"Upton","id":2,"last_name":"Conway","state":"AL"}
{"city":"Columbus","first_name":"Kibo","id":3,"last_name":"Horton","state":"GA"}
```

However, I'd like to nest the produced objects into an JSON array as follows:

```
[
    {"city":"Salt Lake City","first_name":"Ryan","id":1,"last_name":"Dalton","state":"UT"},
    {"city":"Birmingham","first_name":"Upton","id":2,"last_name":"Conway","state":"AL"},
    {"city":"Columbus","first_name":"Kibo","id":3,"last_name":"Horton","state":"GA"}
]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to a snowflake account at the moment, so I apologise for the untested solution :(  I think you are looking for `array_construct` which you can read [about here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/array_construct.html)

I expect something like this could work

```
COPY INTO @%mytable
  FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(objs)
    FROM (
       SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
         'id', id, 'first_name', first_name,
         'last_name', last_name, 'city', city, 'state', state
       ) as objs FROM mytable
    )
  )
  FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = JSON);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a single great solution today.

@tgo's answer will work, if your dataset is small. But if it's large, the created array will cross the 16MB Snowflake limit and the query will fail.

I *hate* to suggest that, but if you *really* need this, just construct JSON yourself, something like this

```
COPY INTO @%mytable FROM (
  SELECT '['
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_JSON(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
         'id', id, 'first_name', first_name,
         'last_name', last_name, 'city', city, 'state', state
       ))
       || ',' 
       as objs FROM mytable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ']'

)
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = CSV)
```

One gotcha is that the last row in your result JSON will have a trailing `,` at the end - depending on what you use to parse it, it might work or not. If not, you could insert an extra trailing value, e.g. `null`, if it doesn't hurt.